# the parameters K ang u in Gaussian distribution

Tags: distribution, gaussian

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i06BK.png)
Who can tell me what the parameters underlined in the picture mean?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please insert your image directly instead of linking to it, as the link may break in the future, leaving a useless Q/A here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**K** and **U** in the **`Gaussian distribution`** are the eigen values coming from `covariance matrix`.The eigenvalues in this case represent the magnitude of the spread in the direction of the principal components. If your data has a diagonal covariance matrix (covariances are zero), then the eigenvalues are equal to the variances:

Comment: yes it basically describe the direction of the principle component

Comment: One more question, which of the three eigenvalues is this?Does it matter?